# Text only under the image and not between if another resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a div box with an image and and text. I want that the text only float under the image if the resolution of the display is smaller than a bigger resolution.

Here is a draft what I mean:
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160821/gxfkmcre.png

Comment: Never I want that the text get over the border of the display!

Comment: You should give us some code here because we can't reproduce your problem without seeing where is the problem

Comment: I am happy that my answer helped you :) vote up please :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@media` queries for that. If you want to target small screen then you can use this

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
   /* your css code goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for smaller screen resolution like that

```
@media(min-width: 420px)
{
  p{display: block;}
}
```